# Can a non-console app also produce colored output in the Visual Studio output window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, colors, console

I have a webapi project that I would like to output colored output in the Visual Studio 'output window' while I'm debugging.

In a console application you can do this as follows

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Write($"test");
```

But in a webapplication where I use Debug.WriteLine(); this does not work.
Is there some way in which the TextWriterTraceListener that outputs to the console can receive instruction to output color?

I have found [a VS Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput) that might provide a 'hack' on Line basis, but that's not what I want.

Comment: I am trying to use "Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("www");” in the Program .cs in ASP.NET Core Web API project. It is possible to output colored text.
Could you describe your specific operation environment? is there any difference from the step I've done?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `ILogger`, you'll get log messages in your console.

Per your example:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
_logger?.LogInformation($"test");
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0